# CSS to target Windows Phone 7 gives strange margin

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-7, media-queries

I'm trying to add a .css file that targets Windows Mobile, and i get a strange right margin on my site in wf:

[here is a photo to show the problem](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11855903/wp_margin.jpg)

I tried setting all elements with margin right 0 and removing pieces, with no luck.
does anyone encountered this issue?

**EDIT:**
I found the problem, it seems to be a bug on windows phone on rtl websites
when i removed the rtl from the html the site shows correct.
As a temporary solution i removed rtl from the html and placed on the container div.
[here is the stripped example](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11855903/wf7rtl.htm)

Does any one knows this bug or what can be done to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: could you post your css code?